# Passing variables through a href link from one page to another page

Tags: pages, variables

On my registration site I have a CPT called "event". In my "Events" page I list these events and create a "register" link for each one towards the "Registration" page:

```
$events = new WP_Query( array( 
'post_type' => 'event'
) );
while ( $events->have_posts() ) : $events->the_post();
    ?> <a href='<?php bloginfo("wpurl"); ?>/registration'>register</a> <?php
endwhile;
```

In my "Registration" page, I want to retrieve the $events->post->ID value corresponding to the event that has been clicked. How to do that?

Comment: I guess it would be easier to give an answer if you posted some of your current code examples.

Comment: I still use the `query_vars` filter to add `x` and then `get_query_var( 'x' )` to retrieve the value. Do you use the same?

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: No problem, I edited my question to include my code.